# Ajax, JS and "-"'s

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, cordova, expressionengine

Does anyone know why the ajax statement here won't accept the '-' symbol. I've had trouble with this in the past and had to change a lot of things in the backend of my site to send the "_" instead and it worked. Is there a way to make the ajax script accept the '-' sympbol?

```
$("#events").append("<img src='"+data[i].event-image+"'></a>");
```

This code is part of an ajax call to get some JSON data that my website is sending out. "event-image" is the name of my field. The consol throws an error saying can't find "image". So the dash is making the code ignore the first part "event-". Any thoughts on how I could rectify this, other than changing the field on my site to be "_". Let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-` is used for subtraction.  You can do it like this though:

```
data[i]["event-image"]
```

`variable.property` is equivalent to `variable["property"]` in javascript.

Comment: Exactly, nothing to do with Ajax.

Comment: YOU...ARE...BRILLIANT! Thank you! Life saver, lovin' this site. Quickest way to get answers.

Answer (score 3):

Just try using `data[i]["event-image"]`.